# Cannot access OSGI service provided in Rifidi Edge Server (RFID Middleware)

Tags: osgi, middleware, rfid, spring-jms, osgi-bundle

I have installed **Rifidi edge server** (open source RFID middleware provide services as osgi bundles) on windows7 and I am trying to develop a java application to connect and communicate with Rifidi edge server. I tried in two ways, firstly from an application external to Rifidi Edge Server and secondly from a OSGi bundle internal to rifidi edge server following link **http://wiki.rifidi.net/index.php?title=EdgeServerJMS** , I face following problems in both ways.

**1) From application external to Rfifid Edge Server**

Code of **rifidi.xml** is

```
 <bean id="connectionFactory"  class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name ="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:1099"/>
        <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true"/>
     </bean>

  <bean id="topic" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
        <constructor-arg value="org.rifidi.edge.external.tags"/>
    </bean>
```

and code of **java file** is

```
   Connection connection;

   ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("rifiditest/rifidi.xml");

   ConnectionFactory cf=(ConnectionFactory) ctx.getBean("connectionFactory");  
        
   connection = cf.createConnection();
          
   Destination dest1=(Topic) ctx.getBean("topic");

   Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

In this case code is working fine but giving Exception **java.io.EOFException** at   **Session session = connection.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);**

**2) From OSGi bundle internal to Rifidi Edge Server**
In this case i am using 2 ways to get data using JMS. Firstly by using JMS ConnectionFactory and JMS Topic object and secondly by MessageListener interface

**2)(i) By using JMS ConnectionFactory and JMS Topic object**

Code of **spring xml** is

```
      <bean id="connectionFactory"  class="org.apache.activemq.spring.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">         
         <property name ="brokerURL" value="vm://externalBroker"/>
        <property name="useAsyncSend" value="true"/>
     </bean> 
     <bean id="externalMB" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
                <constructor-arg value="org.rifidi.edge.external.tags"/>
      </bean> 

   <bean name="hello" class="com.javaworld.rifiditest.Helloworld"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop" >
     <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
     <property name="externalMB" ref="externalMB"/>
   </bean>
```

Code of **com.javaworld.rifiditest.Helloworld.java** is

```
    Connection connection;
  
    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
   
     Session session = connection.createSession(false,  Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
   
     connection.start();

     Destination dest=externalMB;

     MessageConsumer consumer=session.createConsumer(dest);

 TextMessage m=(TextMessage) consumer.receive();

     System.out.println("---"+m.getText());

     connection.close();
```

It is executing fine but execution **hangs** at **TextMessage m=(TextMessage) consumer.receive();** and not giving any error.

**2)(ii) By using MessageListener interface**

> When using **org.rifidi.edge.internal** not getting any data and it is giving warning warning, **WARN org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext:357 - Failed to start jmx connector: Cannot bind to URL [rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jmxrmi]**

When using **org.rifidi.edge.external.tags** no error and not getting any data.

**Kind help me to solve this PROBLEM**

Comment: "It is not working" is not a very useful error description. What actually happened, what did you *expect* to happen, was there any error message, etc...

Comment: Dear Neil,Thanks a lot for your kind reply.I am not getting any error message.I expect to get POJO provided by Rifidi Edge Server using <osgi:reference id="confac" interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" bean-name="externalBrokerConFac"/>
<osgi:reference id="externalMB" interface="javax.jms.Topic" bean-name="externalNotificationsDest"/> in spring xml. But on doing this my Osgi Bundle is not reading xml. I am exactly following these links http://wiki.rifidi.net/index.php?title=Edge_Server_Architecture http://wiki.rifidi.net/index.php?title=EdgeServerJMS to access services of rifidi edge server

Comment: @NeilBartlett Please ask if you still not getting my question.I have created & exported my own service in OSGI bundle & accessing it from another OSGI bundle using <osgi:reference...> tag in spring xml, Bundle is reading xml & I am getting object from exported service easily.But when I am trying to access services exported by Rifidi edge server,my bundle is not reading xml.For your reference these links http://wiki.rifidi.net/index.php?title=Edge_Server_Architecture & http://wiki.rifidi.net/index.php?title=EdgeServerJMS shows what I am exactly trying to do.Kindly help me out with this problem.

Comment: Hello @NeilBartlett , I am getting following error when I am using osgi:reference tag **ERROR org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies
.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor:395 - Unable to create appli
cation context for [com.javaworld.rifiditest], unsatisfied dependencies: none
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.osgi.service.importer.support.A
bstractOsgiServiceImportFactoryBean.isMandatory()Z**

Answer (score 0):

Don't know anything about Rifidi edge server, but from OSGi/JMS perspective, the solution depends a little on what you want:

- If you want to run your own application within the OSGi framework the Rifidi server runs in, you need to create a bundle and subscribe to the JMS topic name (according to [the link you indicated](http://wiki.rifidi.net/index.php?title=EdgeServerJMS)) `org.rifidi.edge.internal` (the name on your question mark).
- If you want to run your own application outside the Rifidi server OSGi framework (as a separate VM), the JMS topic name is `org.rifidi.edge.external.tags`. In that case you need to set-up JMS in your own application as well of course. From your post I cannot determine whether you succeeded in that at your step 1.

Answer (score -1):

Rifidi 3.1 now supports rest and mqtt integration with example app

Download latest version here

http://sourceforge.net/projects/rifidi/files/?source=navbar

Wiki

[Wiki.rifidi.net](http://wiki.rifidi.net/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Comment: Do you also have quesion-specific suggestion/experience too?